# about play2 framework json knowledge

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

play2 framework json :

```
case class P(
  val name: String,
  val age: Int,
  val address: String
)
val pList = List(
  P("a", 18, "USA"),
  P("b", 20, "USA")
)
Json.toJson(pList)
```

Why does this doesn't compile?

Comment: Please give the community more information to reproduce the problem. First the play version number, second your imports, there are at least four Json classes in play and the most important give us your compile error.

Comment: You can drop the `new` keyword since they are not needed in combination with case classes.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at the [API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.package) and the example on the [play! website](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaJson). They provide a comprehensive guide regarding JSON. As the `play.api.libs.json` package only contains seven JSON data types (`JsObject`, `JsNull`, `JsUndefined`, `JsBoolean`, `JsNumber`, `JsArray` and `JsString`) you will have to define your own format.

**Taken from the [API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.package):**

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String, friends: List[User])

implicit object UserFormat extends Format[User] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): User = User(
    (json \ "id").as[Long],
    (json \ "name").as[String],
    (json \ "friends").asOpt[List[User]].getOrElse(List()))
  def writes(u: User): JsValue = JsObject(List(
    "id" -> JsNumber(u.id),
    "name" -> JsString(u.name),
    "friends" -> JsArray(u.friends.map(fr => JsObject(List("id" -> JsNumber(fr.id),
    "name" -> JsString(fr.name)))))))
}

//then in a controller:
object MyController extends Controller {
   def displayUserAsJson(id: String) = Action {
      Ok(toJson( User(id.toLong, "myName", friends: List())))
   }
   def saveUser(jsonString: String)= Action {
     val user = play.api.libs.json.parse(jsonString).as[User]
     myDataStore.save(user)
     Ok
   }
}
```

Good luck!